# Why I don't get the $data information from form with AJAX in CakePHP?

Tags: php, ajax, forms, cakephp

I have a simple form in CakePHP. In my view I have this:

```
<form method="POST" action="" class="contact_form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="data[Contact][name]" value="<?php echo $el['Contact']['name']; ?>" placeholder="Dein Name"/>
        <div class="error error_name"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="mail" aria-describedby="emailHelp" name="data[Contact][email]" value="<?php echo $el['Contact']['email']; ?>" placeholder="Deine E-Mail-Adresse"/>
        <div class="error error_email"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="data[Contact][title]" value="<?php echo $el['Contact']['title']; ?>" placeholder="Betreff"/>
        <div class="error error_title"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea class="form-control" id="description" name="data[Contact][description]" placeholder="Deine Nachricht" rows="10"><?php echo $el['Contact']['description']; ?></textarea>
        <div class="error error_description"></div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" id="send" class="btn btn-primary" value="Senden">
</form>
```

I try to send an email with AJAX. In Conroller I have an component with function to send an email when every input have value. When I comment AJAX I get the values from inputs but when AJAX is working I have an information in console that there is no $data. Below is my Controller and AJAX.

```
if($this->request->is('post')){
    $data = $this->data;

    $errors = array();

    if(!$data['Contact']['name']){$errors['name'] = 'Bitte geben Sie einen Namen ein';}
    if(!$data['Contact']['email']){$errors['email'] = 'Bitte geben Sie eine E-Mail-Adresse ein';}
    if(!$data['Contact']['title']){$errors['title'] = 'Bitte geben Sie einen Titel ein';}
    if(!$data['Contact']['description']){$errors['description'] = 'Bitte geben Sie eine Nachricht ein';}

    if(count($errors) > 0){

        $result = array('res'=>'no', 'list'=>$errors);
        $el['Result'] = $result;
        $el['Contact'] = $data;
        $el['Contact'] = $el['Contact']['Contact'];

        $this->set('el',$el);
    }else{

        $result = array('res'=>'yes','list'=>'Vielen Dank für das Senden einer E-Mail');

        $txt = $data['Contact']['name'].'<br><br>'.$data['Contact']['description'];
        $subject = $data['Contact']['title'];
        $from = $data['Contact']['email'];

        $this->Ajax->mailsend($txt, $subject, $from);
    }
}

$('.contact_form').submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    let name = $('#name').val();
    let title = $('#title').val();
    let mail = $('#mail').val();
    let description = $('#description').val();
    console.log(name, title, mail, description);
    $.ajax({ 
        type:'POST',
        url:'../Strona/contact',
        dataType:'json',
        crossDomain:false, 
        cashe:false, 
        contentType:"text/javascript",
        data:{
            name: name,
            title: title,
            mail: mail,
            description: description,
        }
    })
    .done(function(data){
        if(data.res === 'yes'){
            $('.contact_form').html(data.list);
        }else{
            $.each(data.list,function(k,v){
                $('.error_'+k).append(v);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Any idea where am I doing a mistake?

In my console, in the network I have the errors:
- Notice (8): Undefined index: Contact [APP\Controller\StronaController.php, line 627]( and in 628, 629, 630, 637 line)

And something like this in the end:
{ "code": 500, "name": "View file "Strona\json\contact.ctp" is missing.", "message": "View file "Strona\json\contact.ctp" is missing.", "url": "/Strona/contact" }

My version is CakePHP 2.10.19

The stack trace of this error is:

2020-05-15 17:05:17 Error: [MissingViewException] View file "Strona\json\contact.ctp" is missing.
Exception Attributes: array (
  'file' => 'Strona\json\contact.ctp',
)
Request URL: /Strona/contact
Stack Trace:

## 0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Kogni-fit\lib\Cake\View\JsonView.php(107): View->_getViewFileName('Strona\json\con...')

## 1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Kogni-fit\lib\Cake\Controller\Controller.php(968): JsonView->render(NULL, NULL)

## 2 C:\xampp\htdocs\Kogni-fit\lib\Cake\Routing\Dispatcher.php(200): Controller->render()

## 3 C:\xampp\htdocs\Kogni-fit\lib\Cake\Routing\Dispatcher.php(167): Dispatcher->_invoke(Object(StronaController), Object(CakeRequest))

## 4 C:\xampp\htdocs\Kogni-fit\app\webroot\index.php(117): Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))

## 5 {main}

Comment: Please be a little more specific as to what errors you are receiving, post the complete error message, and in case it's an error on the server side, please include the stacktrace of that error too, it would be in your apps error logs (`/logs` or `/app/tmp/logs`). ps. please always mention your exact CakePHP version (last line in `lib/Cake/VERSION.txt` or `vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.txt`) - thanks!

Comment: Have you tried debug ($this->data) or debug ($this->request->data) or debug ($this-getRequest()->getData())  ?

Comment: Thanks for advices. I edit my question and add the errors and my version of CakePHP. I will try to look into logs and try to find stacktrace of my error.

Comment: I added the stacktrace of my error.  If i understand it good i dont have json view. But i dont know what is this view and what it exackly do. I tried to read about it in documentary but still dont know how to creat and connect it together. Its not clear for me.